# How to implement OAuth 1.0 in a desktop application using C# .Net

Tags: c#, windows, oauth, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I am not able to implement oauth in window based app. I have tried C2QB but when I run it, browser hangs and doesn't responds.

I tried the C2QB example from: 
[Github-Quickbook](http://github.com/IntuitDeveloper/C2QB-library-for-Windows-CUI-and-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8BGUI)

I try to connect to Quickbooks online.

Comment: Make a Tutorial for example: http://deanhume.com/home/blogpost/a-simple-guide-to-using-oauth-with-c-/49

Comment: why my question got down vote.?

Comment: Because you don´t ask a specific problem, and questions for code samples or tutorials are off-topic. Here can you read what a off-topic question is: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Specific problem is that I am not able to implement Quickbooks online oauth login.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You must name a specific problem with things you have tried and were you stock and code example which not work.

Comment: I have tried C2QB but when I run it, browser hangs and doesn't responds.

https://github.com/IntuitDeveloper/C2QB-library-for-Windows-CUI-and-GUI

Comment: Have you submitted a ticket to them yet?  https://github.com/IntuitDeveloper/C2QB-library-for-Windows-CUI-and-GUI/issues

Comment: I had also wrote in their forum but didn't receive the reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time of struggle I found out that the **INTERNET EXPLORER** was causing the problem. **The code provided by Intuit is fine and working good**, I just had to change some settings for IE to stop it from freezing.

> Goto Control Panel > Internet Options > Advanced > **Check** Use
>   software rendering instead of GPU rendering